# Reduce frame rate FPS kinect openni_launch

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-fuerte, rate, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am running two programs at the same time so the computational cost is too high. Hence, i thought in reducing the frame rate of the kinect. I am using openni_launch and fuerte. Does anyone know how to reduce the FPS or whether it is possible?

Thank you very much!

Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54360/reduce-frame-rate-fps-kinect-openni_launch/) by [anto1389](https://answers.ros.org/users/3308/anto1389/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can skip frames to reduce frame rate.

Write this line in the terminal

set param name="camera/driver/data_skip" value="10"

and then run

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

This will drop 10 frames and output 2-3Hz data, whereas default value is 0 (which output 30 frames/sec without any dropping)

---

Originally posted by [usman](https://answers.ros.org/users/4430/usman/) with karma: 81 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FBernuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4508/fbernuy/) on 2013-04-11**:
I tried this and didn't work. Instead I used dynamic_reconfigure with the openni running. Here is the command I used: "$ rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam set /camera/driver data_skip 9"